# How to use DATEDIFF SQL Server function and still benefit from the index?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My SQL statement includes the following where clause:

```
DATEDIFF(day,LastActivityTimestamp,getdate()) > 90
```

But the index on the LastActivityTimestamp does not play here. How can I rewrite it to take advantage of the index?

Comment: FYI, try using `GETDATE()-90` in place of `DATEADD(day,-90,getdate())` When working in "days", you can just add/subtract integer days from a `datetime` without `DATEADD()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the following still uses a function, but does allow the use of an index on `LastActivityTimestamp`, which may be what you're asking for:

```
LastActivityTimestamp < DATEADD(day,-90,getdate())
```

If that's not what you're asking for, you may have to add more information to your question about exactly what you're trying to do/seeking to avoid.

Comment: No, this is totally it. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, it does not seem to work. The count of rows returned with your WHERE clause is the same as without, like it does not make a difference. However, my clause returns the right count. So, something is missing.

Comment: @mark - oops. It should be `DATEADD`, not `DATEDIFF`. Edited.

Comment: I have found it too. Still using DATEDIFF, but with 90, rather than -90.

Comment: @mark - yeah, the version with `DATEDIFF` kind of works, but it's relying on funky conversions of dates to and from `int`. The `DATEADD` version more clearly states "I want to find everything with a last activity more than 90 days ago"

Comment: Got you, I will use DATEADD

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid the use of a function is to hardcode the date range.  (`getDate()` is also a function.)

```
 Where LastActivityTimestamp < @startDateRange
```

I suggest you edit your answer to provide more specific details about what your real, final objective here is.

Comment: Yea, you are right. I should have phrased the question differently. I did now.